# No results from $wpdb->get_row()

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I'm trying to read data from my WP db where I've added a custom table. Hereunder the code:

```
add_shortcode('modifica','f_modifica');

function f_modifica()
{
    $chimod = $_POST['chimod'];
    echo $chimod; // OK IT PRINTS THE CORRECT VALUE

    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->mg_nomi WHERE id_nome = %d",'$chimod');
    echo $result->id_nome; // NO RESULTS
}
```

Well, here is some additional info:

1- `mg_nomi` is the table name

2- `id_nome` is the primary key (integer 11)

3- `$_POST['chimod']` is the (integer) parameter I receive from another form with submit button and hidden field

I need only one row because I have to put values into fields in order to update them.

Already tried with:

1- `$wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->mg_nomi WHERE id_nome = '$chimod');`

2- `$wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->mg_nomi WHERE id_nome = '22');`

3- `$wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare(("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->mg_nomi WHERE id_nome = '22'));`

4- `$wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->mg_nomi WHERE id_nome = '$chimod',ARRAY_A");` this one with `echo $result['id_nome']`

5-perhaps all the other variations of the above...I think...

Already did other query that works great, like 
`$wpdb->get_results();` or `$wpdb->delete();`

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: `'$chimod'` - that is a text literal containing the literal characters `$`, `c`, `h` and so on. You should go read http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by assigning the table name to a variable.

`$tabella = "mg_nomi";` and updating the query as follow

`$result = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $tabella WHERE id_nome = '$chimod'");`

It works great. I'm going to try also `$wpdb->prepare()`